# How do I change the thickness of the lines in an Excel chart?

Tags: excel, charts, f#

I managed to create a chart in an Excel worksheet with the following code:

```
let chartobjects = chartSheet.ChartObjects() :?> ChartObjects
    let chartobject = chartobjects.Add(400.0, 20.0, 550.0, 350.0)
    chartobject.Chart.ChartWizard(Title = "P&L and Benchmark",
                                  Source = chartSheet.Range("A1", "C" + (string (slen))),
                                  Gallery = XlChartType.xlLine, PlotBy = XlRowCol.xlColumns,
                                  SeriesLabels = 1, CategoryLabels = 1,
                                  CategoryTitle = "", ValueTitle = "NAV")
    chartobject.Chart.ChartStyle <- 5
```

The series plotted have many data points (about 6,000) and fluctuate (stock price data). For this reason the chart lines appear very thick. I would like to make them thinner. This can be done interactively in Excel. Is there a way to do this from F#?

Comment: What library are you using? or are you using the native interop?

Comment: I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, and I just figured out that even though I set the chart type as xlLine as above the chart appears with type xlLineMarker. This is the reason the lines appear so thick. I tried the type xlStackedLine and the lines appear Ok (not thick) but that is not the type of chart I need.

Comment: I managed to solve my problem, but not to answer my question. I was mistaken in assuming the lines were thick. They looked thick because there were thousands of line markers being shown. So the issue was to get rid of the line markers, which were showing up even though I specified `Gallery = XlChartType.xlLine`. By adding an argument `Format = X` with X either 2 or 10 this is accomplished. All other values for X, from 1 to 11, fail to get rid of the line markers. The line `chartobject.Chart.ChartStyle <- 2` seems to change only the chart colors.